# Merge rows in the same DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm trying to merge two rows into one row. They're both in the same database and table.

Example:

```
        column1    column2    column3    column4    column5    column6
row1    value      value      value      null       null       null
row2    null       null       null       value      value      value
```

I tried using table.Merge(table) but that didn't seem to do anything. How can I merge these two rows so that it's just

```
        column1    column2    column3    column4    column5    column6
row1    value      value      value      value      value      value
```

Comment: How do you define which rows will be "merged," and how do you define which value for each column the resulting row will have?  There's no built-in function to do that for you, you need to define the logic for it.

Comment: There's nothing out-of-the-box if that's what you're asking for. You'll need to do it manually.

Comment: I think using `sum` for each column will do the trick, but I never tried to sum `null` with `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in function to do this for you.  As such you have to do this manually.  First determine the rows to be merged, and run over the columns to merge them.

```
DataRow target = table.Rows[0];
DataRow source = table.Rows[1];

for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    target[i] = target[i] ?? source[i];
}

table.Remove(source);
```

The sample above iterates over all the columns of the two rows and assigns values from source where target is null.  After the merge it removes the source row.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have two DataRows `dr1` and `dr2` from same DataTable, it is straight-forward using `Linq` :

```
var merged = dr1.ItemArray.Zip(dr2.ItemArray, (e1, e2) =>e1 ?? e2).ToArray();    
dr1.ItemArray = merged;
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using Kami's solution as it was posted first but I appreciate the Linq version